# How to update only the year of the date column in a table - sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I was looking for the query which can update only the year of the date column to 2019.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Are you asking some question or providing some answer? It is unclear. If you are asking question, Provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: Hi...its an answer only ....

Comment: @APC oh is it..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can,

if the field of the date for you mydate from table_name, you can do:

```
Update table_name 
set column_name = Add_months(sysdate, -(extract(year from sysdate)-extract(year from  mydate))*12) 
where <where_condition>;
```